# Getting "Can't find devices to link to [projectname]" when getting auth_code from Google NEST, any way to emulate a device?

Tags: google-home, nest-api

Getting **"Can't find devices to link to [projectname]"** when getting auth_code from Google NEST, any way to emulate a device?

It sounds like there use to be but now that NEST migrated to Google I can't find any emulators that are current and use a Google account/login.

Comment: If you could provide more details as to how your project is configured and the steps you are taking to get that error, it will help the community be able to help you further.